# Branch by cloning - Must I make modification on default in order to see the branch?

Tags: mercurial

I am coming from CVS background.

I try to perform branch by cloning.

The current default tree looks like this from `hello` project.
[image]

---

1. I try to clone a project out from 'hello' to 'hello-branch-by-clone'.
2. I did modification on 'hello-branch-by-clone' and commit.
3. I did not do any modification on 'hello'.
4. I perform push from 'hello-branch-by-clone' to 'hello'.

[image]

I expect to see a **branch** but I didn't.

---

This time, I try another way around.

1. I did modification on 'hello-branch-by-clone' and commit.
2. I did modification on 'hello' and commit.
3. I need to pull from 'hello' to 'hello-branch-by-clone', and merge.
4. I perform push from 'hello-branch-by-clone' to 'hello'.

This time, then only I can see the **branch**
[image]

---

By applying cloning technique, is there any way I can have a **branch** view, without having explicitly modify the default repository (`hello`)

Comment: What do you mean by "on a separate branch"?

There's only one commit following the one labelled "modification on trunk", so your GUI client is showing you everything correctly.

Did you mean that you wanted a named branch? Could you draw or indicate how you expected the output to look?

Comment: You would only see that if you had changesets in main repository that you didn't have in your clone. You don't see diverging paths like that unless you actually have parallel branches. Since you don't have that, the history just goes straight upwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no fork because no two changesets share a parent.

A cloned repository isn't special in any way. It's identical to the original. Commits to it are identical to commits in the original repo. They aren't notionally tagged as being on a branch. A clone is just a nice way of having another work area that you can do some work (including commits) without effecting the original.

A fork occurs when two or more commits have the same parent. Often this happens when using clones, but it may not. If there's only one changeset with the same parent, there is no fork.

After your first sequence you've introduced just one changeset (4) which is which has the old tip (3) as it's parent, so it's still a straight line. Only when you introduce a second changeset parented by (3) will you see a fork.

Now remember, even though you 'push'ed the changeset back, and the original "Hello" repo contains all 4 changesets, it's working directory is still pointing to changeset (3). It will stay that way until you run 'hg update' inside it. This means that if you were to make a commit in "Hello" it will be based upon (3), and then a fork will appear. It doesn't matter when this commit is made.

This is what you did in your second sequence.

Hope that helps.

---

I've tried to use the term 'fork' in this, because 'branch' has lots of meanings, including the 'hg branch' command which does some slightly different things.